# Site reloads when firing an AJAX-form-submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to update my mySQL database with ajax. The browser should NOT reload or go to a different URL when I hit the submit-button.

My form looks like this:

```
<form class="directmsg_form" method="post" id="directmsg_form" name="directmsg_form">
    <div class="form-group" id="directmsg_subject"></div>
    <input class="form-control" style="display: none" id="directmsg_receiverid" name="directmsg_receiverid">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="directmsg_text" name="directmsg_text" placeholder="Nachricht"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="directmsgsend_button" id="directmsgsend_button" style="font-size: 20px">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" style="font-size: 20px"></span>  Nachricht senden
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

And here is the javascript-code which fires the AJAX:

```
document.getElementById("directmsgsend_button").addEventListener('click',function (){
    var data = $("#directmsg_form").serialize();
    $.ajax({                
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'directmsg_send.php',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function(){ 
            $("#directmsg_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; übertrage Daten ...');
        },
        success : function(response){                       
            alert(response);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

After hiting the submit-button I get the javascript-alert like I should - and then the site reloads and I don´t know why.

Comment: Add an 'event.preventDefault()' to your callback.

Comment: A submit button will always submit the form, you need **event.preventDefault** to block the default behaviour.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Ah, I heard of that, but I am newbee. Could you tell me what the "Callback" is? - I added it now after alert(response); and it keeps reloading the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add event.preventDefault() to your function:

```
document.getElementById("directmsgsend_button").addEventListener('click',function (event)
                {
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = $("#directmsg_form").serialize();

                        $.ajax({                
                        type : 'POST',
                        url  : 'directmsg_send.php',
                        data : data,
                        beforeSend: function(){ 
                            $("#directmsg_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; übertrage Daten ...');
                        },
                        success : function(response){                       

                            alert(response);

                        }
                    });

                    return false;

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you should add add preventDefault() to your callback function in click event. Your code would look something like this.

```
document.getElementById("directmsgsend_button").addEventListener('click',function (event)
                {
                //will prevent default behavior, reloading page in this case
                event.preventDefault();
                var data = $("#directmsg_form").serialize();

                        $.ajax({                
                        type : 'POST',
                        url  : 'directmsg_send.php',
                        data : data,
                        beforeSend: function(){ 
                            $("#directmsg_button").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-transfer"></span> &nbsp; übertrage Daten ...');
                        },
                        success : function(response){                       

                            alert(response);

                        }
                    });

                    return false;

                });
```